# Why Illegal state exception is throwing when I am browsing the Files on sd card?

Tags: android, listview, browser, android-arrayadapter

```
06-06 10:06:22.404: I/System.out(418): Files:[Ljava.io.File;@406f43a8
06-06 10:06:22.414: I/System.out(418): List all Items:[/sdcard/MyVideo, /sdcard/.android_secure]
06-06 10:06:22.414: I/System.out(418): Files:[Ljava.io.File;@406f43a8
06-06 10:06:22.414: I/System.out(418): List all Items:[/sdcard/MyVideo, /sdcard/.android_secure, /sdcard/LOST.DIR]
06-06 10:06:22.414: D/AndroidRuntime(418): Shutting down VM
06-06 10:06:22.414: W/dalvikvm(418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3835)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:314)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.videosdcard.FileBrowser.getFiles(FileBrowser.java:71)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.videosdcard.FileBrowser.<init>(FileBrowser.java:37)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.videosdcard.VideoSDcard$1$1.onClick(VideoSDcard.java:240)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-06 10:06:22.434: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 10:06:33.103: I/Process(418): Sending signal. PID: 418 SIG: 9
```

I am downloading the video from URL. And saving it on SD card. I wanted to browse the files on sd card. So Iam getting all the Directories which is present on a folder . This I could be able to do it.

I wanted to display all the Items using listview from Array list.

Here, I am getting all the Items using array list from sd card. When I am using Array adapter to populate in a list view, error is throwing here.

Error is shown above.

My code is Child class derived from parent class. I mean, second class--FileBrowser

```
            /*Create Method to get all the Files and Folders from the current Directory we are in */

        getFiles(f.listFiles());
            System.out.println("List all Files:"+f.listFiles());
        }
        private void getFiles(File[] files) {
        items=new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Item files:"+items);
            for(File file : files){
                 System.out.println("Files:"+files);
                 items.add(file.getPath());
        }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_LV_list);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't @Override onCreate method in your code.

Comment: -1 for hitting the file system in your constructor.

Comment: @Christopher Perry Iam new to Android. Sorry and now I learned from the mistakes, thanks!

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan, My gripe isn't Android specific. You should never do work in your constructor, especially file system or network access. A constructor should be used to construct your object. Methods are what do work.

Comment: Your latest edit seems to have removed much of your code leaving  fragments behind, please consider fixing that.

Comment: @Chris Stratton-- Sure, I will fix that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities
>   before onCreate()

instead of creating `FileBrowser` constructor for adding Adapter to ListView you will need to use `onCreate` method or `onResume` for initializing ListView and accessing system services.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<< set layout here
   this.Context=context;
    f=new File(path);
    System.out.println("Full SD card path:"+f); 
    getFiles(f.listFiles());
    System.out.println("List all Files:"+f.listFiles());               

}
```

Also use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for getting SD-CARD path instead of static sting:

Comment: Let's also note that file system access (or network access) in the constructor of a class is bad design. You never want to write code where the simple act of creating your class has side effects.

Comment: @Christopher Perry--Yeah, I learned from my mistake ! I am new to Java and Android. It is my fault and now Iam learning from the basics, thanks for pointing out my mistake !

Answer (score 0):

**Context is not available in the Activities Constructor**, it is only available in the Activity.onCreate() method and beyond.

So you have to use activity's **onCreate** method

Answer (score -2):

The stack trace says all you need to know:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
>   Activities before onCreate()

Comment: It's a clue, but not by itself an explanation.  The fact that an ArrayAdapter depends on on the Layout Inflater service might not have been obvious without a more careful reading of the log, Android source code, or potentially the documentation (if that fact is actually mentioned in the docs)

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I disagree. He is trying to hit the file system in his constructor, which is called before onCreate. Hence the description in the exception, and hence the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, you would be wrong - the specific problem is not hitting the file system, but trying to use a service to do so.  Read the error message more carefully, and see the referenced line of ArrayAdapter.java in the android sources.

Comment: If it's wrong to say "don't hit the file system in your constructor" then I'd love to be wrong all day my friend.

Comment: Your error is that hitting the file system in the constructor, while debatable in the abstract, **is not the problem in this case**.  The exception is quite explicitly attempting to use a **system service** at a time when doing so is illegal.  Try a test with a simple file access in a constructor, and you'll see that it does not cause **this particular** exception - it may well not cause any exception at all, wisdom of doing so aside.

Comment: Nothing in my posted answer is in error. Also, I like to point out programming errors when at all possible. Although you are technically correct that the issue at hand is using a Service to hit the file system, my general advice of not hitting the file system in the constructor solves not only this issue, but a plague of other possible issues this particular programmer may cause in the future. So while your answer is technically correct, mine is much more valuable.